# Are there any singular points in the map?

Tags: differential-geometry

> In Euclidean three-space, we can define paraboloidal coordinates $(u,v,\phi)$ via
>   \begin{align*}
> x = uv\cos\phi,\quad y = uv\sin\phi,\quad z = \frac{1}{2}(u^2-v^2)
> \end{align*}
>   Are there any singular points?

This question feels a bit vague to me because I don't really know how to graph this. I know that there wouldn't be a singular point for a paraboloid of the form

> \begin{align*}
> x^2+y^2=z
> \end{align*}

But seeing these three equations makes me unsure now.

Comment: [Ernie060’s hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2950324/265466) is definitive, but you can guess where there might be problems just from looking at the equations: what happens at $x=y=0$, for instance?

Comment: That would be the origin but I didn't think that would be singular because it needs to be "nasty" behavior such as a cusp, see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SingularPoint.html)

Comment: The $(u,v,\phi)$ coordinate system “collapses” there.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Look at the Jacobian matrix 
$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}\\
\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial v} & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial v} & \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial v}\\
\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \phi} & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \phi} & \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial \phi}\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The singular points are the points where the determinant of the Jacobian matrix is zero.

Comment: I have worked out the transformation matrix you have above to be
\begin{align*}\Large
\begin{pmatrix} 
v\cos\phi & u\cos\phi & -uv\sin\phi \\
v\sin\phi & u\sin\phi & uv\cos\phi \\
u & v & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
So the Jacobian
\begin{align*}
\Large J(u,v,\phi) = \frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(u,v,\phi)}\Large  &= \Large \begin{vmatrix} 
v\cos\phi & u\cos\phi & -uv\sin\phi \\
v\sin\phi & u\sin\phi & uv\cos\phi \\
u & v & 0 
\end{vmatrix}\\
\Large &= \Large u^3v - uv^3 = 0\text{ if }
\begin{cases}
u = 0\\
v = 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Comment: So there are singular points whenever $u$ and/or $v$ is zero, yes? And I would like to find the inverse transformation matrix but I cannot make $u$, $v$ and $\phi$ the subjects of the original equations.

Comment: Note that $J=uv(u^2-v^2)=0$ implies $u=0$, $v=0$, $u=v$ or $u=-v$. You can calculate the inverse matrix by just inverting it, you don't necessarily have to write everything in terms of $x$, $y$, $z$. If you want to know the points $(x,y,z)$ where the $J$ is singular, note that $z=0$ if $u^2-v^2=0$ and that $x=y=0$ if $uv=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. So the inverse would be what I've worked out below then.
\begin{align*}\Large
\begin{vmatrix}
-\frac{v\cos\phi}{u^2-v^2} & -\frac{v\sin\phi}{u^2-v^2} & \frac{u}{u^2-v^2} \\
\frac{u\cos\phi}{u^2-v^2} & \frac{u\sin\phi}{u^2-v^2} & -\frac{v}{u^2-v^2} \\
-\frac{\sin\phi}{uv} & \frac{\cos\phi}{uv} & 0 
\end{vmatrix} &= \frac{u^2(\sin^2\phi + \cos^2\phi)}{uv(u^2 - v^2)^2} - \frac{v^2(\sin^2\phi + \cos^2\phi)}{uv(u^2 - v^2)^2}\\
&= \frac{(u^2 - v^2)}{uv(u^2 - v^2)^2} = \frac{1}{uv(u^2 - v^2)} = \frac{1}{J(u,v,\phi)}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Also, I'm asked to find the basis vectors $\Large\frac{\partial}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial}{\partial v}, \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$ in terms of $\Large\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and basis one-form  $du, dv, d\phi$ in terms of $dx, dy, dz$. But I don't completely understand what this means... What it's asking for me to do...

Comment: Use the chain rule for derivatives.

Comment: Use the chain rule on what exactly?

Comment: I'll give an example: $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$.

Comment: Oh right, thank you. I get that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial u} &= v\cos\phi\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + v\sin\phi\frac{\partial}{\partial y} + u\frac{\partial}{\partial z}
\end{align*}
And I have that
\begin{align*}
dX^i\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial X^j}\right) = \delta^i_j
\end{align*}
So would that make
\begin{align*}
du = \frac{1}{v\cos\phi}dx
\end{align*}